# Attempt to add an element to a group in Javascript causes "... not an object." error even though the element is an object

Tags: javascript, svg.js

Description: Attempting to add an element to a javascript group causes "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object." even though I have verified using typeof that it is an object.

```js
let d = SVG('board').size(100, 100);

function createElem(elemId) {
  let elem;
  elem = d.rect().attr({
    id: elemId
  });
  return elem;
};

function main() {
  'use strict';
  let elem, elemId, s;

  elemId = `elem101`;
  elem = createElem(elemId);
  alert(elem); // Returns ‘elem101’ although elem is an object. --A
  s = d.group();
  s.add(elem); // Appears to work fine up to this point

  // However, replacing the previous line with the following
  // three lines of code causes an error
  elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  alert(elem); // returns ‘[object SVGRectElemnt]’; Why? -- B
  // In A, the alert returns the element id of ‘elem101’
  // but here in B it returns the rectangle object.
  // Why this difference?
  try {
    s.add(elem); // Causes error: “TypeError: Argument 1 of
    // Node.appendChild is not an object.”
    // I am unable to add the element returned by getElementById
    // to the group.
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.js"></script>

<div id='board'></div>
```

Adding a code snippet to the body

Comment: Be careful when copying code around -- you had a "right single quotation mark" rather than an "apostrophe" in your code, which is invalid. I'm assuming that wasn't actually the problem with your code, since it would have been a syntax error.

Comment: I've added a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to demonstrate the code, but apparently there's something missing from the example code. Maybe an SVG element? I'm not familiar with the library. If you can edit it so that it reproduces the issue, I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I have slightly modified the code and wrapped it around the proper html. I have tested it on my desktop with Firefox, Chrome, and Edge and it works as described. I have replaced the previous uploaded code with the tested code. I am able to reproduce the alerts and the problem. For some reason, it does not work with Internet Explorer but you can use any of the other browsers mentioned. How to test? --> Put the entire code snippet in a local file and run from the desktop browser.

Comment: Okay. The point of using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) was to avoid having to make people copy all of the code into a local file. They could run it from the browser. If you read that linked article, it has step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Got the code into a Stack Snippet. At the end it does cause an error that can be ignored.

Comment: I edited your snippet a bit. There's no need for a `head` and a `body`; the snippet takes care of that. I also put a `try/catch` around the code so it would output the actual error message. In Chrome, it shows `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`. That does seem a bit odd, considering `SVGRectElement` is a `Node`... May have something to do with the way svg.js has implemented `add`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`add`](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/manipulating/#add) expects an SVG.js object, not an DOM Node. You can get the SVG.js object from the DOM Node using [the `instance` property](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/referencing/#instance).

Here's the same snippet, now using `elem.instance`, which doesn't throw the error. That said, it won't add the same element twice, so it doesn't do much...

If you want to get the SVG.js object by ID, you can use [the `SVG.get()` method](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/referencing/#by-id) to get the element

```js
let d = SVG('board').size(100, 100);

function createElem(elemId) {
  let elem;
  elem = d.rect().attr({
    id: elemId
  });
  return elem;
};

function main() {
  'use strict';
  let elem, elemId, s;

  elemId = `elem101`;
  elem = createElem(elemId);
  alert(elem);
  // Returns ‘elem101’ although elem is an object.
  // Apparently SVG.js overrides the toString() method of their objects to
  // return the id property if present.
  s = d.group();
  s.add(elem); // Appears to work fine up to this point

  elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  alert(elem); // returns ‘[object SVGRectElemnt]’; Why? 
  // Since you're using DOM methods, it's retrieving a DOM object.
  // To get the SVG.js object, use an SVG.js method
  // elem = SVG.get(elemId);

  try {
    s.add(elem.instance); // does nothing because of the add() call above 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
  // OR
  try {
    s.add(SVG.get(elemId)); // does nothing because of the add() call above
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.js"></script>

<div id='board'></div>
```